# What does Windows 7 Professional have that Home Premium doesn't?

Tags: windows-7, comparison

The compare site lists XP mode, Join Domain and network backup. There must be other differences. If not, what are the real values in these features? I'm trying to decide which to get. I will be running a home network with several XP machines and one or 2 Windows 7.

Comment: Nope, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions) there's also a comparison list with some more info.

I find it interesting that in Windows 7 unlike in Vista the higher editions only add more features while keeping all the features from lower ones.

Comment: +1 good link - It is almost as if Microsoft have realised that people do not like confusion!

Comment: That helped. Remote Desktop is a desired feature but I suppose there are open source alternatives.

Comment: For me interesting part is also the XP virtual machine. But this is probably not so important for home use.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this link: [Which one is right for you?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/compare)

[image]

Comment: That's a fine start but since I figure win 7 has more than 9 features, i was hoping for any further insights. Maybe no one knows. Are all current available installs win7 Ultimate?

Comment: Most current installs are Ultimate due to this is what people were using in RTM. Please note that the above is only showing the major features. All editions contain all basic tools which are not worth listing (such as command prompt, telnet, paint etc.)

Comment: The 3 features that Professional has and Home Premium doesn't are usually needed by businesses, hence the **Professional** in the name. You don't really need any of the extra features.

Answer (score 0):

All features are worth listing...  especially the ones which aren't available in every version.  Microsoft has failed us by not providing those lists.